# How to remove Element from list in Unity (in Inspector, Children of Elements)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I have QuestList which contants scriptable objects.
I want Delete Elements when the quest is complete.

In "Element 0" there is another element "Completed Objectives"
in the first quest "Quest A" when you start up the game quest is set to 0/1
when you finish objective quest is setup to 1/1
(I need to delete Quests so they don't show up after they completed)

how do i delete  Elements in runtime?
how i can add them?
I been googling around 2 hours to find answer for this...

I try out this but doesn't work.

```
public void RemoveQuest()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < completedObjectives.Count; i++)
        {
          if(completedObjectives[i] == questToRemove)
          {
                completedObjectives.Remove(completedObjectives[i]);
          }
        }
    }
```

[image: picture1]

[image: picture2]

[image: picture3]

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the collection while looping through it.

In your case you can just use this:

```
completedObjectives.Remove(questToRemove);
```

Comment: `You can't modify the collection while looping through it.` that's true for `foreach` ;) you *can* do it with `for` but should most probably `break` after the first hit otherwise you get out of range ;) But in this case you're right of course I don't see a need for the loop at all

Comment: The alternative would be RemoveAt which takes the index (would work the original code example.  For loop does not care if the collection is modified because it does not directly use the collection for looping.